# VBA: How to delete an entire row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete a data from a worksheet so I can upload a new data. The problem is when I delete it responses with a runtime-error '1004'.

[image]

Here is the function:

```
Sub deleteOldData(str As String)
    Dim tBookings As ListObject
    Set tBookings = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").ListObjects("tBookings")

    tBookings.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    tBookings.Range.AutoFilter field:=tBookings.ListColumns("Practice").Index, Criteria1:=str

    If tBookings.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
       Exit Sub
    Else 
       tBookings.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
    End If

    tBookings.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

How can I avoid this issue?

So it looks like this: when I import a new csv file the old data which I have existing has to be deleted based on the practice. because the new csv file has a new updated data based on the practice.

Comment: Did you try `...).EntireRow.Delete` ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow

Comment: Yes i did, but the same issue

Comment: Step through this subroutine using the VBA debugger to check which line actually throws the error. It looks like you're not deleting a typical range; instead you're trying to delete all visible cells in the row below your AutoFilter'd table. Is this what you are meaning to do?

Comment: tBookings.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
this line is throwing the error. I replaced it with : 
With tBookings.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0)
            .Resize(tBookings.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
        End With
but instead of deleting the data i want to delete, it deletes all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I also added a **col** variable to avoid repeating code.

```
Sub deleteOldData(str As String)
    Dim tBookings As ListObject: Set tBookings = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").ListObjects("tBookings")
    Dim col As Integer: col = tBookings.ListColumns("Practice").Index

    tBookings.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    tBookings.Range.AutoFilter Field:=col, Criteria1:=str

    If tBookings.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
       Exit Sub
    Else
       tBookings.ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    tBookings.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works without error but it deletes all the old data and not only the old data with the Criteria1:=str. I want to delete only these with the Criteria1:=str

Comment: The code I posted deletes all rows the data with ``Crietria1:=str``. What do you mean by old data? Post two images with an example, one ``As Is`` before running the procedure and another ``To Be`` after running it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEvHR.png     
here is an image and it looks like this :  when i import a new csv file the old data witch i have existing have to be deleted based on the practice. because the new csv file has a new updated data based also on the practice.

Comment: I just tried the code I posted with the table you just posted using ``Call deleteOldData("CD")`` and all the records in column ``Practice`` with the string ``CD`` were deleted. The other records where not deleted! Give me some feedback.